# Listing the contents of a database file which is to be displayed in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm using an open source fingerprint recognition program written in C# ([SourceAFIS](https://sourceafis.angeloflogic.com/)) which stores the enrolled users in a .dat file.

To read from the .dat file I use:

```
List<MyPerson> database = new List<MyPerson>();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

if (File.Exists(Database))
{ 
    using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Database)) 
    database = (List<MyPerson>)formatter.Deserialize(stream); 
}
```

Where `Database` is the path of the database.dat file.

With this I can use `database.Add(Enroll(Image, Name));` to enroll people into the system.

The enroll function is as follows:

```
static MyPerson Enroll(string filename, string name)
{
    MyFingerprint fp = new MyFingerprint();
    fp.Filename = filename;
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    fp.AsBitmapSource = image;
    MyPerson person = new MyPerson();
    person.Name = name;
    person.Fingerprints.Add(fp);
    person.Fingerprints[0].Finger = Finger.LeftThumb;
    Afis.Extract(person);
    return person;
}
```

I was wondering if it were possible to list each user in the database and have them displayed in one of my ASP.NET MVC views? How am I able to check the way in which the database is written to?

**EDIT:**

MyPerson and MyFingerprint classes that are declared in the controller

```
[Serializable]
class MyPerson : Person
{ public string Name; }

[Serializable]
class MyFingerprint : Fingerprint
{ public string Filename; }
```

Comment: what do you mean with: How am I able to check the way in which the database is written to?

Comment: I am quite new to it so my knowledge is fairly limited but what I mean is how is it formatted so that it can be read from accurately. From my understanding, the fingerprints templates are kept within this database file as well meaning it won't simply be names making it a little more complex to list.

Comment: the `database` object you create there is just a list of objects of type `MyPerson`. What properties does this class have?

Comment: The class is setup with the [Person class](http://www.sourceafis.org/documentation/html/T_SourceAFIS_Simple_Person.htm). Code for this is as follows:         [Serializable]
        class MyPerson : Person
        { public string Name; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `database` object in your example isn't a database in the traditional sense.  Rather, it's the `List` of `MyPerson` objects serialized as a file, including their fingerprint templates and any other values the `MyPerson` class contains. There is a [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx) that describes the format used for writing the file, but since the file just represents an object of type `List<MyPerson>`, there's not a lot to gain by trying to read the binary format of the file. I've used serialization numerous times and have never bothered to look at the file format.  It's much safer to just let the `BinaryFormatter` class handle the work.

If you haven't already, you should look at the documentation for serialization on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx).  If your `MyPerson` class has any chance of being changed in the future, you should look at the section on [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752.aspx) to avoid an potential problems down the road.

The `database` object can be passed directly to a view as shown in the following sample code. You will likely need to update the namespace in the view to reflect your project. The code in the `Index` method is just to demonstrate the concept: it's not reflective of good app architecture.

Controller

```
public class MyPersonController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {
        List<MyPerson> database = new List<MyPerson>();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (File.Exists(Database))
        { 
            using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Database)) 
            database = (List<MyPerson>)formatter.Deserialize(stream); 
        }


        return View(database);
    }
}
```

View, listing only the `Name` property

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPerson>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what to update the namespace to for the model. MyPerson is currently being declared in my controller. The code for it has been given above.

Comment: It will be whatever your controller namespace is, along with the controller name, then MyPerson.  Something along the lines of `ControllerNamespace.ControllerName.MyPerson`.  You can also use the Add View command in Visual Studio to create a strongly typed view and just select the MyPerson class in the Add View dialog.

Comment: I thought it may be that but I was getting an error. The error was related to the MyPerson class not being public. Making it public fixed the issue and it now works. Thank-you.

Comment: If it weren't too much trouble, could I also ask if it is possible to pull the filename? Above I have edited in the code I use to enroll the fingerprint if you need to see that.

Comment: Are you referring to the filename used in the Enroll function?  If so, where is that filename coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have used Sample project in SourceAFIS as your base. You better use a real database to store information of people and images. This has way too many advantages over file based storage.

- allows multiple clients
- fixes concurrency problems
- provides network access
- provides easy paging
- does not require file system access

You can use even SQL Server Express edition to start with.

Now, answers to your questions

1. Yes you can do list you users on your MVC page, with pictures of them side by side.
2. You do not need to check for a "database" which your users have been written to, since all users are stored on same DB, which you can use a discriminator field to filter the users that you want.

You have noted you your knowledge is limited. You should start extending your knowledge by researching and reading. You may start reading stuff about Entity Framework or Linq 2 Sql.

After you have created a DB and loaded your dat files to that DB, the code will be like this (using Linq2Sql).

```cs
public class MyPersonController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {
        var people = PersonStore.GetAllPeople();

        return View(people);
    }

    public ActionResult Image(int id) {
        var image = PersonStore.GetPersonImageById(id);

        return BinaryResult(image.Content, image.MimeType);
    }
}
```

and your view

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonModel>
<table>
    @foreach (var Person in Model)
    {
        <td>@person.Name</td>
        <td><img src="@Url.Action("Image", new { id = person.id })"></td>
    }
</table>
```